# Can I use UpdateSingleSalesforceObject in Interactive Email Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, interactive-email

Can I use Interactive Email Form to do a Salesforce object update?

-How can I send a variable (Salesforce id from the journey) into email form as a hidden attribute?

-I need to make a Salesforce object update on click of the submit button in Interactive email form.Is this possible? if not what should be followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question, It is as same as how you will get the subscriber key from salesforce via normal email using personalization strings. You can use `_subscriberKey` for salesforce ID and `emailaddr` for email address and add it in hidden attributes.

[image]

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

To your second question, It is possible. Because if you look at the HTML part of Interactive email form in the code view, you will find ampscripts on re-directing to cloud pages using [CloudPageURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function.

So, you can use ampscript in Cloud Page / Landing page to get the subscriber key here as well. Once you get the subscriber key then you know which data extension to lookup with and get the results and update salesforce using `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject`

```
%%[
Set @subscriberkey = [_subscriberkey]
]%%
```

Below is the screenshot if it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to send the Salesforce record ID on to the landing page?

Comment: Hi @CloudDot, I have just tired it in my instance and I can able to fetch the subscriber key / salesforce record id from the landing page. You can get other data's from look up from data extension and update salesforce. Hope this helps.